# Is it possible to have non-static html code as a return value in Blazor

Tags: c#, html, blazor

I want to automate most of my blazor table with return statements from functions.

This piece of Blazor C# code gives errors on the onclick statement and the GetData statement:

```
protected Object GetStandardLine(string id, DateTime rowDate)
    {
        return @<td style = 'color: var(--tekst-kleur-donker1); background-color: var(--eerste-kleur)' @onclick = "() => Redirect(id, rowDate)" > @GetData(id, rowDate).Item3 </td>;
    }
```

Errors: "Can not convert lambda expression to Object type"

```
protected RenderFragment GetStandardStreefLine(string id, DateTime rowDate)
        {
            return @<td style='color: var(--tekst-kleur-donker2); background-color: var(--eerste-kleur)' @onclick="() => RedirectStreef(id)">@GetAmounts(id, rowDate).Item1 @if (GetAmounts(id, rowDate).Item4 != "") {<RadzenButton Size="ButtonSize.Small" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Info" Icon="info" MouseEnter="@(args => ShowTooltip(args, id, rowDate, new TooltipOptions() { Duration = null}))" />}</td>;
        }
```

This shows no errors but the code no longer compiles.

Can this work? Or do I abandon this approach?

Comment: well you're missing the outer quotes - `@"<td...</td>";` but it's not clear if that's the problem or just a transcription error.

Comment: I don't know if what you are trying to do is possible, but you could use components instead for this purpose.

Comment: If I add these I get as Error: "Method name expected"

Comment: Create a small repro of the type of thing you are trying to do and we can probably help more. In the short term, change `Object` to `RenderFragment`

Comment: @MisterMagoo This worked awesome thank you!

Comment: Why not just write a loop in the Razor?

Comment: @MisterMagoo What about the one I added in the post?

Comment: @CaiusJard Not all lines are the same.

Comment: @HaroldVandeputte, "Not all lines are the same" does not prevent to do your code logic in the razor part. What effectively prevents you from doing this in razor?

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine Ok, so I have a table where all columns (9 of them) are the same except for the "id" as seen in the piece of code above. Which I could solve with a list of Id's. Except that the second column is different. I could use a loop from the 3th column, that might be a solution indeed.

Comment: _"shows no errors but the code no longer compiles"_  can't be true. Have a good look in the ErrorList and Ouput windows.